# Can't use URLs mapped in /etc/hosts for Webdriver.io

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriver-io

I'm using webdriver for my integration tests. I want to run the test suite for the url:
`https://test.url.net`
*but* I have some constraints that are beyond my control.

1. I need to run the tests on my local environment.
2. I **cannot** use localhost as my url

I solved this by adding an entry in `/etc/hosts/` to map localhost to my url

```
$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1 test.url.net
```

when I run webdriver targeting `https://test.url.net` it just hangs and cannot connect, however, when I try to target `https://localhost:443/` the test opens (and fails due to the constraint that we can't use localhost as a domain).

Is there a way to provide webdriver with a mapping of url to ip address?

Comment: Are you sure you can not test the localhost with the respective port mentioned using webdriverio? I remember doing it for some reason.

Comment: I am also facing similar issue. From selenium I can use `http://127.0.0.1:3000/some-endpoint` and `http://localhost:3000/some-endpoint` But when I use `http://my-domain:3000/some-endpoint`, it gave me `org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException`. Here is my question => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72708717/selenium-cant-access-web-server-by-domain-name-in-circleci-environment

Answer (score 1):

https://test.url.net is directing only 127.0.0.1 / localhost. But you have to mention the port number.

try `https://test.url.net:443` in browser manually and check if the website loads.

if yes then use this url with port number in webdriver.io