# Selenium can't access web server by domain name in CircleCI environment

Tags: linux, selenium, continuous-integration, circleci, circleci-2.0

In CircleCi config, I added `my-domain` to `etc/hosts` in-order to access local webserver by domain name.

For example => http://my-domain:3000/some-endpoint

But when I start Selenium-testing using the following config.yml, I can only call `http://127.0.0.1:3000/some-endpoint` and `http://localhost:3000/some-endpoint` from Selenium.

When I try to use `http://my-domain:3000/some-endpoint` from the Selenium, it gave me `org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException`

```
steps:
      - checkout
      - run:
          name: Add my-domain in etc/hosts
          command: |
            echo '127.0.0.1 my-domain' | sudo tee -a /etc/hosts
            cat /etc/hosts
      - run:
          name: Start server for testing
          command: |
            cd ${DIR}
            . venv/bin/activate
            python3 server.py
          background: true
      - run:
          name: Start Testing
          command: ./gradlew test --stacktrace
```

Comment: Would mind adding a `cat /etc/hosts` in the next step just to ensure the domain is there? I used your `echo` solution and it worked for me, I added a fake domain and ran an `nc` command over the port 22. Could you post the whole `config.yaml` too?

Comment: Sorry @JuanFontes I can't post the whole file here. Yeah, the domain I added exists in `/etc/hosts` Now I can access `my-domain` from CURL command. So, I think the problem is coming from selenium. `org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException`. If I switch URL to http://127.0.0.1:3000 in selenium, it works. But still can't call `my-domain` from selenium. Do you have any clue?

Comment: Hi @Necromancer, no problem. I asked you to post the file just to see if another step was changing something.. Yeah, it looks like an issue with Selenium, since you were able to run a `curl` over the fake domain, but unfortunately, I have no experience with Selenium tests. :( sorry for that.

Comment: @JuanFontes It's fine. I updated my question.

Comment: By the way @Necromancer.. CircleCI runs each step in a new shell, so what if you move the `echo` command to inside the selenium test step? If it doesn't work, do you know https://local.gd/? It's a service that redirects any request to your localhost, so you can set up your domain like `http://my-domain.local.gd:3000` and the requests will be redirected to `127.0.0.1:3000`. I know it doesn't answer your question, I'm just trying to give options until you fix the issue.

Comment: @JuanFontes I appreciate your effort but I can't use other domain apart from `my-domain` because Backend side has limited access.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245804/discussion-between-necromancer-and-juan-fontes).